# How did Hela know that the Gauntlet was a fake?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, thor-ragnarok

So in *Thor: Ragnarok*, we see Hela mentioning that the Gauntlet in Odin's treasure room is a fake.

How did she know that it was a fake, considering the fact that she was locked away by Odin for about as long as atleast the age of Thor (1500 years)?

Also, Thor would have met Eitri in the last 1500 years, and he was the one who made the Gauntlet. So how did that happen?

Comment: Hela is a cosmic being she would have sensed the power. Anyway the gauntlet in Odin's throne room was a loophole they had shown it in the dark world they needed to clear the air up. Getting Hela to declare it fake was a pretty good way to do it.

Comment: @AvnishKabaj we have never been told about the powers of cosmic beings in MCU. Also, Gauntlet wasn't supposed to exist back then

Comment: She must have known about the gems

Comment: @AvnishKabaj I think it is pretty clear that she is talking about the Gauntlet as fake, as it clearly doesn't have the Stones

Comment: The infinity gauntlet in Ragnarok had fake stones.

Comment: How does she know that this is a Gauntlet that houses the Infinity Stones? Combined with the fact  that actual Gauntlet is left handed also confirms this.

Comment: She said something about Odin has sudden change of heart and that he wanted to become a god of good. And Odin has so many cover ups which he ultimately used to various reasons mainly keeping peace. So putting up gauntlet for people to see, that Odin has the gauntlet could make the impression that there'll be no harm will coming from that way. So Odin may have been planted a fake one while Hela is around, before she was banished

Comment: It isn't even hinted in MCU or comics that Odin had created the Gauntlet. The concept of a weapon like Gauntlet that could channel the power of the Stones came with Thanos.

Comment: I mean I might not be an expert at knowing how to detect radiation and tell apart radioactive material from just warm material, but I think I would be able to tell the difference between a giant plaster and metal and cement statue of the Elephant's Foot of Chernobyl... and the actual Elephant's Foot at Chernobyl.

Answer (score 9):

It's just a retcon to cleanup the confusion for having two gauntlets, no need to overthink about it. From [CinemaBlend](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/1722179/why-thor-ragnarok-included-that-scene-with-the-infinity-gauntlet):

> That came about because in Thor 1, the reason that it's in this movie is because someone who went through that movie, frame by frame, looking for Easter eggs was like 'Oh! The Infinity Gauntlet!' And then from that point on, they were like, 'That damn Infinity Gauntlet, what are we going to do with that thing?' It's like, there, but it also [exists] somewhere else in the universe. How do we deal with that? And then we realized like, Odin... Hela goes through and she goes, 'Fake. All of that stuff that's in here is fake.' Basically the thing we were trying to go for was that Odin somewhere along the line realized that everyone knew that the Infinity Gauntlet was on Asgard and in the safe keeping of Odin, then no one would come looking for it. So he made a fake one, and let everyone believe... Basically, a fake launch code.
>
> We brought that over -- like here's an opportunity to take something off the plate of Markus and McFeely, who are doing Avengers 3 and 4, and have plenty else to worry about with I don't know -- what -- 60-plus characters in one movie?

**In-Universe**, Hela knows a lot about Odin's secrets which Thor and others didn't have any idea about. So we have to assume that she knows this secret too.

Comment: This retcon just created more confusion. Is it mentioned anywhere that Gauntlet was such a tool that even existed at that point? Just for Fan's entertainment they put something that defies the story and logic. Did the Gauntlet even exist back then (as for all intents and purposes, the idea came into Thanos's mind)?

Comment: @AbhishekMishra Why do you think the Gauntlet was something that Thanos came up with? There's no evidence for that at all in the MCU as far as I recall.

Comment: @AbhishekMishra how did idea came into thanos's mind? maybe idea was lying around before it too, he just executed it

Comment: Because Ebony Maw mentions that nobody had the might nay the nobility to wield two Infinity Stones. Why would anyone need to create a device that could channel powers of all the Stones if nobody ever wielded more than one?

Comment: @AbhishekMishra did he said "nobody had the might have the nobility to have knowledge abotu infinity gauntlet"?? **No**, so point not taken

Comment: @AnkitSharma if nobody wielded more than one Stone why would anyone make a Gauntlet? It's like having train tracks but no concept of train tracks to start with

Comment: @AbhishekMishra people can have blueprint in advance too and Odin had fake gantlet with fake stone proved it already that eh know about a gantlet

Comment: @AbhishekMishra Ebony Maw isn't an all knowing God within the MCU, you can't take his statements as fact. There's a lot of bluster and exaggeration going on when he talks about Thanos. Even if Thanos was the first to actually wield two Infinity Stones, that doesn't mean he was the first to try to do so; somebody in the distant past - well before Ebony Maw existed - could have forged a Gauntlet and tried to take possession of multiple stones, and been defeated before they obtained a second.

Comment: @AbhishekMishra how do we know someone didn't try to make something that could wield the stones? Celestials exist. Other beings exist. It is very well possible and likely that someone *believed* they could wield all the stones and that the issue was *containment* of that energy not necessary biological ability. Even then, if anyone believed using them granted god-like power, maybe they believed that having all of them would then make you immune to the adverse effects - that the stones would cancel each other out and allow you to wield them unharmed.

Comment: We don't know why someone tried. Clearly they were insane. Maybe they were forward-thinking. Who knows? Thanos certainly did *not* design the gauntlet, so the presumption there is that *someone* believed the theoretical possibility and maybe ended up killing themselves the moment they grabbed one stone - or gave up when they saw the soul stone's high price.

Worth mentioning that Thanos is a member of an alien race - and was raised as a farmer no less. He managed to use it with nonfatal burns as the repercussion. The same with the Hulk. Now imagine Ego at full might trying to use it!